# Understanding the properties on ajax event object in callback context

Tags: jquery, ajax, file-upload

I am using the Aquantum jQuery plugin to upload files to a LAMP site.

Works fine.. but I also need to do a success callback to put the uploaded filename and file URL
in a form field.

The upload plugin is here:

http://aquantum-demo.appspot.com/file-upload

(very clean, cool file upload widget, IMO)

Here's the callback code: 
( the **file name** part works well.. but how do I grab the **file URL** too?)

```
jQuery('#fileupload').bind('fileuploaddone', function (e,data) {

    jQuery('textarea').val( "<p><a href='" + NEED_FILE_URL_HERE + "' target='_blank'>" + data.files[0].name + "</a>" ); 

});
```

Comment: I looked at that plugin and the example code it provides. The URL for the uploaded file would never be available in the JS - it depends on the server it was uploaded to. Their example upload.php appears to put in a .url in the JSON return, so it should be data.url. If that's not it, just console.write(JSON.stringify(data)); to see where it's stored. If this is correct, let me know and I'll move it to an Answer so that you can mark it correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I heard from the author of the jQuery UpLoad plugin. 
His suggestion works great now that I know the result
properties the callback can see..

> This should alert the first file url (based on the assumption that
>   you're using the example package):

```
$('#fileupload').bind('fileuploaddone', function (e, data) {
     alert(data.result[0].url); });
```

> Note that browsers with support for multiple file selection but no XHR File upload (Opera, Firefox 3.6)
>   might return multiple objects as part of the result array.